# Converting custom date format imported from excel in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, rename

I am struggling with a few things after importing an excel table to R.

When I imported it in R, it changed it to numerical values (the same ones I'd get changing the cell type to "Generic" in Excel). I googled it and tried several ways to fix this, such as the following

However, what I get is the date in the following format: yyyy-mm-dd.
Also, 43466:44105 includes every DAY between those ranges.

1. Am I supposed to type the numbers one by one? I.e. 443466 (for Sep-19), 43497 (for Oct-19) and so on.
2. How can I change it to a "mm-yy" format?

On top of that, I am not sure how to rename all the date columns once I figure out how to convert those numbers into dates. I know how to rename multiple elements inside multiple columns, but the same function (transform) can't be applied to multiple columns (as far as I know).

Thanks in advance for any help you can give, apologies if it's a silly question but I'm a newbie trying out newbie things.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider reading [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As a start, you can use ```dput``` on the data frame that you get from importing the excecl file and paste the output here. That way, others can simply copy and paste the code and start working. Second, please consider adding the output you expect, e.g. for the first 3 rows and columns. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I just used dput and the output is pretty long, are you sure it's ok to paste all that?  Also,the only output I am expecting is to have the date appear as it was in my Excel table (i.e. mm-yy format) instead of numerical values, and to have the values under each column appear as percentages. I thought I had already made that clear?

Comment: Regarding you first question: Yes, it is ok. However, ich you really think that the output might be to much you can easily limit the output. For example, just use ```dput(df[1:20, ])```. Regarding the second question: You think you made it clear. But giving concrete input-output examples often clarifies possible missunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created some sample data:

```
#// sample data
df <- structure(list(region = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("london", 
"north east", "west midlands"), class = "factor"), X43466 = c(5, 
4, 5), X43497 = c(6, 7, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
#// check the input
df
#>          region X43466 X43497
#> 1    north east      5      6
#> 2        london      4      7
#> 3 west midlands      5      8
```

Here is how you would convert the column names to date format:

```
#// get column names
names <- colnames(df)[2:3]
#// remove leading x
names <- sub('.', '', names)
#// convert to numeric
names <- as.numeric(names)
#// convert from Excel date format
names <- as.POSIXct(names * (60*60*24)
           , origin="1899-12-30"
           , tz="GMT")
#// write column names back
colnames(df)[2:3] <- as.character(names)
```

The code for the POSIX conversion may need to be adapted depending on your Excel setting and timezone, but you should be able to sort it out. As a result you should get something like this:

```
#// check the results
df
#>          region 2019-01-01 2019-02-01
#> 1    north east          5          6
#> 2        london          4          7
#> 3 west midlands          5          8
```